# How to add require 'zip/zip' and 'zip' in Gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubyzip

I have two ruby files where one file is using "require 'zip/zip'" with rubyzip version '0.0.9' and other "require 'zip'" with rubyzip version 1.1.7. If use them separately(alone) its working fine.If i combine i am getting error like "no such file to load — zip/zip". How can i solve this?

My Ruby version : 1.9.3

Rails version : 2.3.14

Thanks.

Comment: by combining do you mean merging the content?

Comment: @usmanali I want a way where i can use both 'zip/zip' and 'zip' in Gem file or my ruby files(controllers) or if any other gem that supports both 'zip/zip' and 'zip'.

Comment: @user1770589 Can you confirm that you are referring to https://github.com/orien/zip-zip and http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip?

Comment: @usmanali Thankyou so much for your reply, it worked for me.How can i mark that as answer?

Comment: @user1770589 I ll post it as an answer, you can accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`zip-zip`](https://github.com/orien/zip-zip) is `gem` so you can write it in `Gemfile`. The [`zip`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) however is an `Array` method, so you can use it without having to `require`.